# How to set fontSize for xticks in boxplot using Python pylab module?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to change the fontSize of the labels for y axis using pylab. How could I do?

Answer (score 5):

Its not clear from your question whether you want to change the `xticklabels` or the `ytickslabels`, but you can do both using the `xtick.labelsize` and `ytick.labelsize` options from [`rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

For example, to set a font size of 16:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams

labelsize = 16
rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = labelsize
rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = labelsize
```